# Trying to find "distinctive" font for undistinctive letters - O N T I U

Tags: fonts, print-design, text, font-recommendation

Freelance work for a friend, shirts for a small group starting a startup. After a wild goose chase he now wants a "distinct" font. He gave me sample fonts where the "distinct" marks are all in letters that aren't in the company name.

How do I get around this? The letters C, I, N, O, U, and T, aren't usually fun in fonts.

Do I need to make my own font?

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct"? If you can't find a font for what you want then yes draw your own. You can always use the samples you have for inspiration.

Comment: Can you show us the sample fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Here's where the word "creative" comes in.

Try a search for Novelty or Quirky typefaces. Maybe you can find a stock typeface that will please your client. There are tens of thousands of unmodified stock typefaces that are quite distinctive.

Once you have some likely candidates, you can apply effects to them to modify them in a way to make them unique for your client's use.

You can screen, scan, tone, colour, outline, combine, connect, apply edge effects, and distort normal typefaces.

You can change the weight, set, alignment, and style of a typeface.

You can reverse, stack, tilt, twist, and tip the baseline of each or all the set letters.

Getting the picture? Now, don't compromise the legibility or the readability of your miracle.